# How to return array of functions from required sub page in Express, Nose.js

Tags: node.js, express, multipage

I build an app in **node.js** using **Express** server.
My app contain an index.js page, Dal.js page that will be able to return an array of DB function (insert,delete...).
I tried to do it in this way:
*

> //index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
Dal=require('./Server/DB/Dal')(app);
```

> //Dal.js

```
    module.exports=function(app)
    {
       var add=function(table,values, obj, next){
                 //tha action
       }

       var update=function(table,values, next){
             //tha action
       }

    **return** {
        Add:add,
        Update:update
    }
}
```

*

But it doesnt work!!

What is the problem??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of var in your class you have to to this:

```
var Dal = function(){};// Init class
Dal.prototype = { //define instance function 
   add: function(table,values, obj, next){
             //tha action
   },

   update: function(table,values, next){
         //tha action
   }
;}

module.exports=Dal; //Export your class
```

It should work. 
PS: you have to create an instance (new Dal())

---

**Updated**

In your app.js you just have to do what you were doing

```
Dal=require('./Server/DB/Dal');
var dalInstance = new Dal();
dalInstance.add(...);
```

You use it like this.

Comment: Thank you, How can I call it in the **index.js** page?